# Intellij idea opens static pages in browser with different url formats

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij idea has a nice "open in browser feature" that I use quite often for my static html files. Any html file can be opened in browser in two ways: 1. Idea has an internal web server that serves static content at `http://localhost:63342/<relative path to content>` . 2. Via `file:///<absolute path>` url.

After a recent update (14.0.2) the browser started to open pages as `file:///<absolute path>` although the internal web server is still present and all I need to do is edit the url. Very annoying. I searched a lot but still can't figure out how can I influence this behaviour so all my static pages would open in browser as `http://localhost:63342/<relative path to content>`

Comment: I can't reproduce this in IntelliJ 15.0.2 for mac

Answer (score 1):

Specify the server connection settings:

> In the Host text box, type localhost.
>      Use the Port spin box to specify the number of the port where the built-in web server runs. The port number should be set to 1024 or higher. By default this port is set to the default IntelliJ IDEA port through which IntelliJ IDEA accepts connections from services (63342).
>
> Specify the folder that will be considered server document root. The folders that are under this document root in the project tree will be submitted to the PHP interpreter. The server document root folder will be accessed through HTTP at the above specified host:port.
>
> In the Document root text box, specify the path to the relevant folder. This can be the project root or any other folder under it.

**References**

- [Idea Docs: Built-in Web Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/php-built-in-web-server.html?search=63342)